# Can´t create test database django

Tags: django, django-tests

I´m trying to test a django application, but when I run python manager.py test I got this error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column deals_dealproposal.billing_branch_launcher_id does not exist
```

it´s occurs in

```
 File "/migrations/0008_dynamicpackingtype.py", line 18, in run
for proposal in bulk_proposals:
```

In this point, billing_branch_launcher doesn't really exist, it´s create in migration 27

```
migrations.AddField(
        model_name='dealproposal',
        name='billing_branch_launcher',
        field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, related_name='billing_branch_launcher', to='clients.CoffeeCompany'),
    ),
```

The migration 8 looks like this

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('coffeedeals', '0007_auto_20190315_1642'),
    ('schemas', '0003_dynamicpackingtype')
]

def run(app, schema_editor):
    bulk_proposals = md.DealProposal.active.filter(
        data__negotiation__packing='bulk',
        data__negotiation__packing_type__isnull=False)

    for proposal in bulk_proposals:
        del proposal.data['negotiation']['packing_type']
        proposal.save()

operations = [migrations.RunPython(run, atomic=True)]
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest install the python library

> django-test-without-migrations

Then the migrations file errors don't affect to the tests.

```
pip install django-test-without-migrations
```

add it in INSTALLED_APPS (settings.py)

> Then run :

`python manage.py test --nomigrations`

refer:https://pypi.org/project/django-test-without-migrations/